# ExternalGraphics - gray squares instead

Tags: java, geotools, graphics

I am creating point symbolizer with external graphic, and it works great if I load an image/png, but when I try to load svg file I get gray squares on map

```
StyleFactory sf = CommonFactoryFinder.getStyleFactory();
StyleBuilder sb = new StyleBuilder();
Graphic graphic = sf.createDefaultGraphic();
PointSymbolizer pointSymbolizer = sf.createPointSymbolizer(graphic, "the_geom");
File file=null;
if(tacka.equals("Trigonometrijska tacka")){
    file = new File(PointStyle.class.getResource("/trigonometrijska.svg").getFile());
}else  if(tacka == "Poligonska tacka"){
    file = new File(PointStyle.class.getResource("/poligonska.svg").getFile());
}else if(tacka == "Linijska tacka"){
    file = new File(PointStyle.class.getResource("/linijska.svg").getFile());
}
else if(tacka == "Detaljna tacka"){
    i=1;
}else{
    i=1;
}
graphic.setSize(ff.literal(10));
ExternalGraphic external = 
        sb.createExternalGraphic( "file:///" + file, "image/svg+xml"); 
graphic.graphicalSymbols().clear();
graphic.graphicalSymbols().add(external);

Mark mark1 = sf.getCircleMark();
mark1.setFill(null);
Stroke stroke = sf.createStroke(ff.literal(JSimpleStyleDialog.lineColor), ff.literal(JSimpleStyleDialog.lineWidth));
mark1.setStroke(stroke);
if(i==1){
    graphic.graphicalSymbols().clear();
    graphic.graphicalSymbols().add(mark1);
}
```

I suppose that something is wrong about format but can't figure out what.

---

```
<sld:Graphic><sld:ExternalGraphic>
<sld:OnlineResource xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:type="simple" xlink:href="file:///F:\workspace\AGGF_Geotools\target\classes\trigonometrijska.svg"/>
<sld:Format>image/svg+xml</sld:Format>
</sld:ExternalGraphic>
<sld:Size>10</sld:Size>
</sld:Graphic>
```

Comment: can you try writing the style out as SLD for us.

Comment: I added something, hope it is what you asked.

Comment: does file:///F:\workspace\AGGF_Geotools\target\classes\trigonometrijska.svg resolve to a file?

Comment: yes, there is a file trigonometrijska.svg in F:\workspace\AGGF_Geotools\target\classes\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some exploring (and looking hard at the GeoServer code) I think this is a documentation fail ([updated now](http://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/library/render/faq.html)). The short answer is that you need to add a dependency on `gt-svg` to your project so that your code has access to `SVGGraphicFactory` which is used to convert the SVG found at the URL to an icon to be drawn.

So just add this to your `pom.xml`:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.geotools</groupId>
        <artifactId>gt-svg</artifactId>
        <version>${geotools.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

I also got gray squares, my issue was that I used the code from the outdated

https://github.com/geotools/geotools/blob/main/docs/src/main/java/org/geotools/render/StyleExamples.java

But you need to clear the default symbols first:

graphic.graphicalSymbols().clear()

and make sure to use the correct format.

Here's my code:

```
        StyleFactory sf = CommonFactoryFinder.getStyleFactory(null);
        FilterFactory ff = CommonFactoryFinder.getFilterFactory(null);
        StyleBuilder sb = new StyleBuilder(sf);
        Graphic graphic = sb.createGraphic();
        graphic.setSize(ff.literal(15));
        //we need to clear otherwise the graphics will not be loaded!
        graphic.graphicalSymbols().clear();
        // preferred
        graphic.graphicalSymbols().add(sb.createExternalGraphic(url, "image/png")); // png next
        //alternative
        URL urlsvg = getClass().getResource("/pictures/gcp.svg");
        graphic.graphicalSymbols().add(sb.createExternalGraphic(urlsvg, "image/svg")); // svg
        //fallback
        graphic.graphicalSymbols().add(sb.createMark(StyleBuilder.MARK_CIRCLE, fillColor,fillColor, 1));
        PointSymbolizer pointSymbolizer = sb.createPointSymbolizer(graphic, "the_geom");

        Rule rule = sb.createRule(pointSymbolizer);
                
        Font font = (labelFont == null ? sf.getDefaultFont() : labelFont);
        Fill labelFill = sf.createFill(ff.literal(COLOR_GCP));
        AnchorPoint anchor = sb.createAnchorPoint(0, 0);
        Displacement displ = sb.createDisplacement(4, 4);
        PointPlacement placement = sb.createPointPlacement(anchor,displ,null);
        TextSymbolizer textSym = sf.createTextSymbolizer(labelFill, new Font[]{font}, null, ff.property(ATTR_NAME), (LabelPlacement) placement, null);
        rule.symbolizers().add(textSym);

        FeatureTypeStyle featureTypeStyle = sb.createFeatureTypeStyle("Feature", rule);
        // create a "user defined" style
        Style style = sb.createStyle();
        style.featureTypeStyles().add(featureTypeStyle);
```

Note I did a patch suggestion here:
https://github.com/geotools/geotools/compare/main...dominiquedemunck:geotools:patch-1